# JavaScript check if only one property vlaue is empty in loop

Tags: javascript

I have this array of object:

```
var arr = [
    { value : 'title', text : '' },
    { value : 'product', text : '' },
    { value : 'price', text : '' },
    { value : 'number', text : '' },
];

var error = false;
```

Now, I want to loop through this `arr` array of object and check if only one property (text) is **NOT** empty. If so then stop the loop and set the `error` variable to `false` otherwise `true`;

I am trying this code:

```
arr.every((item)=>{
    if (Object.values(item).includes(null)) {
        error = true;
    } else {
        error = false;
    }
});
```

but not working according to my expectation :(

Comment: `const err = arr.every(({ text }) => text != null && text !== "")`

Comment: @Yousaf will this code stop the loop when there is value on the text property and set the error as false?

Comment: Yes. See: [MDN - every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#description)

Comment: I don't understand why people put the negetive mark !!

Comment: As your question seems not to be answered yet i might have misunderstood your question and as such, my answer is not correct. 
So you want to break if ANY of the text values is empty or only if ALL are empty?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use try and catch.

Something like this :

```
var BreakException = {};

try {
  [1, 2, 3].forEach(function(el) {
    console.log(el);

    if (el === 2) throw BreakException;
  });

} catch (e) {
  if (e !== BreakException) throw e;
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

Answer (score -3):

```
arr.forEach((item)=>{
    if (!item.text) {
        error = true;
    } else {
        error = false;
    }
});
```

Maybe such?
As you can directly use `item` as an object and reference with `.text` to its values.