# Call Blazor method from JS without button click

Tags: blazor

How do I initiate call to DotNet method from JS.

- My index.razor calls JS 'Create' function and passes json filename that need to be opened.
- index.js opens the file and parses its content. As you could see that only after the file is parsed (after satifysing (data[i].name === "something") condition), window.sendName can return value to blazor.
- So, I would like to know how JS(index.js) could initiate call to blazor by itself, rather than initiated from navbar.razor.
- Because when call initiated from navbar.razor as below, navbar is loaded before json is parsed, so cant return proper value.

My code:

```
Index.razor:
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Create", fileName);
}


JS:
function Create(fileName) {
  $.getJSON(fileName, function (data) {
     data.forEach((eachline, i) => {
     if (data[i].name === "something") {
     window.sendName= () => {
            var val = "Abc";
            return val;
     }
     }
     }
  }
}
  

NavBar.Razor:
<a href="" @onclick=getName>GetName</a>

 public string? Name { get; set; }   
 [JSInvokable]
        private async Task getName()
        {
            Name= await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("sendName");
      
        }
```

I tried using example in below link. But doesn't seem to work as I expect.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-6.0#class-instance-examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to create a helper class. The class should have a `JSInvokable` method that raises an `event` when called.

`SendNameHelper.cs`:

```cs
public class SendNameHelper
{
    public event Action<string>? OnNameSent;

    [JSInvokable]
    public Task SendNameAsync(string name) 
    {
        OnNameSent?.Invoke(name);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Register this class as a service in `Program.cs`. Blazor components are now able to inject the service and subscribe to the event.

`Program.cs`:

```cs
// for blazor wasm
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SendNameHelper>();

// if blazor server add as scoped
builder.Services.AddScoped<SendNameHelper>();
```

`Index.razor` should use `IJSRuntime` to call the `create` JS function and pass to the function a reference to the `SendNameHelper` service.

`Index.razor`:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@inject SendNameHelper SendNameHelper

...

@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var sendNameHelperReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(SendNameHelper);

            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("create", fileName, sendNameHelperReference);
        }
    }
}
```

`NavBar.razor` should simply inject the `SendNameHelper` service and subscribe to the `OnNameSent` `event`.

`NavBar.razor`:

```
@inject SendNameHelper SendNameHelper
@implements IDisposable

...

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        SendNameHelper.OnNameSent += HandleNameSent;
    }

    private void HandleNameSent(string name)
    {
        // do stuff with name
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        SendNameHelper.OnNameSent -= HandleNameSent;
    }
}
```

And finally `create` function should use the `SendNameHelper` reference to invoke the `SendName` method:

`JS`:

```js
window.create = (fileName, dotNetHelper) => {    
    $.getJSON(fileName, function (data) {
        data.forEach((eachline, i) => {
            if (data[i].name === 'something') {
                dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('SendNameAsync', 'something');             
            }
        });

        dotNetHelper.dispose();
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But I get error - 1000 Uncaught (in promise) Error: System.ArgumentException: There is no tracked object with id '8'. Perhaps the DotNetObjectReference instance was already disposed. (Parameter 'dotNetObjectId').

Comment: Have you added `if (firstRender)` check in `OnAfterRenderAsync`?

Comment: No, I missed that. Let me try. Thank you.

Comment: Also put `dotNetHelper.dispose();` outside `forEach` loop. The way I had it before the reference got disposed when the first `data[i].name === 'something'` is found but the loop continues, that's why it threw the exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Works perfect now. My application was slower because I had to stop checking data[i].name === 'something' once the condition was true. (using isValid == false).

Comment: Might be better to use a different way to loop through data. A way that allows to exit the loop early. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion. I was able to resolve it.